# Python Tic Toc Toe | GAME is Failing to RESTAR

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

Everything is running smoothly up until the `while` loop breaks and the `else` statement runs and asks the players if they want to play again.

```
else:
        if input("Do you want to play again? Type Yes or No: ").lower() != 'no':
             game_tic()
```

When I call `game_tic()` again the board doesn't refresh. The old moves are still displaying. I thought if I call the `game_tic()` the game was suppose to restart fresh.

Please check out my code:

```
import os

x_moves = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
o_moves = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
numeros= [1,2,3,
       4,5,6,
       7,8,9]

def clear_screen():
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")

def draw_map_choices():
    print("#" * 7)
    tile = "|{}"
    both_set = set(x_moves) | set(o_moves)
    for num in numeros:
        if num in both_set:
            if num == 3:
                if num in x_moves:
                    print(tile.format("X") + '|', end='\n')
                else:
                    print(tile.format("O") + '|', end='\n')

            elif num == 6:
                if num in x_moves:
                    print(tile.format("X") + '|', end='\n')
                else:
                    print(tile.format("O") + '|', end='\n')

            elif num == 9:
                if num in x_moves:
                    print(tile.format("X") + '|', end='\n')
                else:
                    print(tile.format("O") + '|', end='\n')
                print("#" * 7)
            else:
                if num in x_moves:
                    print(tile.format("X"), end='')
                else:
                    print(tile.format("O"), end='')

        else:
            if num == 3:
                print(tile.format(num)+'|',end='\n')

            elif num == 6:
                print(tile.format(num) + '|', end='\n')

            elif num == 9:
                print(tile.format(num) + '|')
                print("#" * 7)
            else:
                print(tile.format(num),end="")

def return_open():
    return sorted(set(numeros) - (set(x_moves) | set(o_moves)))

def player_X():
    clear_screen()
    draw_map_choices()
    print("You can pick from the following number positions: {}.\n".format(", ".join(str(x) for x in return_open())))
    x = int(input("Player X's turn: "))
    if x not in x_moves and x not in o_moves:
        x_moves[x-1] = x
    else:
        print("Pick a location that is open")

def player_O():
    clear_screen()
    draw_map_choices()
    print("You can pick from the following number positions: {}.\n".format(", ".join(str(x) for x in return_open())))
    o = int(input("Player O's turn: "))
    if o not in o_moves and o not in x_moves:
        o_moves[o-1] = o
    else:
        print("Pick a location that is open")


def check_if_won(xo_list):

    #Horizontal MAtch
    for n in range(0, 9, 3):
        if (numeros[n], numeros[n+1], numeros[n+2]) == (xo_list[n], xo_list[n+1], xo_list[n+2]):
            return True

    # Vertical MAtch
    for n in range(0, 3):
        if(numeros[n],numeros[n+3], numeros[n+6]) == (xo_list[n], xo_list[n+3], xo_list[n+6]):
            return True
    #Diagonal Check
    if (numeros[0], numeros[4], numeros[8]) == (xo_list[0], xo_list[4], xo_list[8]):
        return True
    if (numeros[2], numeros[4], numeros[6]) == (xo_list[2], xo_list[4], xo_list[6]):
        return True
    else:
        return False



def game_tic():
    juego = True
    num_turn = 1

    while juego:

        player_X()
        if check_if_won(x_moves):
            clear_screen()
            draw_map_choices()
            print("Player X Won! Congratulations!\n")
            juego = False

        elif num_turn == 5:
            clear_screen()
            draw_map_choices()
            print("Is a DRAW!\n")
            juego = False

        if juego:
            player_O()
            if check_if_won(o_moves):
                clear_screen()
                draw_map_choices()
                print("Player O Won! Congratulations!\n")
                juego = False

        num_turn += 1

    else:
        if input("Do you want to play again? Type Yes or No: ").lower() != 'no':
            game_tic()



clear_screen()
print("Let's Start Our Game of Tic Toc Toe!")
input("Press ENTER when you are ready!")
game_tic()
```

Comment: You are not resetting xmoves.

Comment: I thought once the loop breaks everything resets? How should I go about resetting the moves for both x_moves and 0_moves  at the point where the game gets call again.

Comment: The variables you set aren't erased when the loop ends.

Comment: add `x_moves = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
o_moves = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` at the start of `game_tick`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you!

Comment: @fi11er Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to reset `x_moves` and `o_moves` in `game_tic()`, like this:

```
def game_tic():
    juego = True
    num_turn = 1
    global x_moves, o_moves
    x_moves = [None for i in range(0, 9)]
    o_moves = [None for i in range(0, 9)]
    ...
```

Comment: @M0dem, sure :)

Comment: @M0dem or `x_moves = [None] * 9`

Comment: @Uriel _Humf!_  So un-Pythonic.  :P

Comment: @M0dem `[obj] * n` is actually quite common and considered very "pythonic" (possibly [and not only] regarding the use of operators overloading like the multiplication operator for lists)

Comment: @Uriel: ok for `None` but not for object instances. In that case `[None] * 9` is very good.